# Instrumenting source files when invoking ng build

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/istanbul-instrumenter-loader/

I'm trying to instrument my Angular 7 code when calling `ng build`. How would the following section of my `angular.json` file look?

```
{
    "projects": {
        "my-project": {
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    // ???
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking of instrumenting the code first then running `ng build` but the output of the instrumentation will not include html, css etc. files. So I'm wondering if this can be done on the fly with `ng build`.

Comment: Is it code coverage reporting that you are after with this tool? If so, you could use `ng t --code-coverage` to get that, if you're using the Angular CLI, too.

Comment: @R.Richards Ah yes if you wish to use Karma. I'm using Jest and Cypress and Cypress requires the bundled frontend code which is served to the client to be instrumented :/

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?